# message event listener not working properly

Tags: discord.js

I currently have the following code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION']
});
const db = require('quick.db')

client.on('message', async message => {
    const DmLogger = require('./MainServer/dmRecieving.js');
    DmLogger(client, message, Discord);
    const levels = require('./MainServer/levels/main.js');
    levels(client, message)


    if (message.channel.id === configFile.LoggingChannel) return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;
    let prefix = db.get(message.guild.id + '.prefix') || '~'
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let args = message.content
      .slice(prefix.length)
      .trim()
      .split(/ +/g);
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == prefix + 'info') {
      const commandFile = require(`./Embeds/info.js`);
      return commandFile(client, message);
    }
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == prefix + 'help') {
      const commandFile = require(`./Embeds/help.js`);
      return commandFile(client, prefix, message);
    }
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == prefix + 'fonts') {
      const commandFile = require(`./Commands/font.js`);
      return commandFile(client, msg, args, prefix, message);
    }
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'setup')) {
      const commandFile = require(`./Commands/setup/main.js`);
      return commandFile(client, message, db);
    }
  });
```

Whenever I send a message that includes a command the event listener is firing however it is not detecting the message content.
This module has been working fine for the passed few months its just suddenly erroring after I reinstalled the `discord.js` module.

Comment: I don't know this module, but if you just updated to Discord.js v12, it might have broken a few things. Try to see if the module works differently for v12

Comment: I've never used anything below version 12 of discord.js

Answer (score 2):

In discord.js v13, it is necessary to specify an intent in `new discord.Client()`. Events other than the specified intent will not be received.
[ClientOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions)
[Intents#FLAGS](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS)

To receive the `message` event, you will need the `GUILDS` and `GUILD_MESSAGES` intents.

You mean...

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
    intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
});
```

Or to receive all (including privileged intent) events...

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
    intents: Object.keys(Discord.Intents.FLAGS)
});
```

Also, in discord.js v13, the `message` event has been deprecated, so it is recommended to replace it with `messageCreate`.

```
- client.on('message', async message => {
+ client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
```

Answer (score 0):

Since discord.js v13, you need to declare what your bot is doing with [Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents)

Here's how you declare them :

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
   partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'], 
   intents: ['GUILD_MESSAGES']        
})
```

The GUILD_MESSAGES Intent is essential because it allows your bot to read and reply to messages in guilds.
However, you should check the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents) to see if your bot needs some more Intents