# Having trouble sending a message to a channel with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a bot that sends a message to a channel once a user sends a specific message. I've managed to make it send a message once the bot logs in, but the `client.on()` function won't do anything. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong, thank you in advance!

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.login("<bot token>");

client.once("ready", () => {
console.log("Ready!");

channel.send("hello world"); //This works

const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("<server id>");
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("<channel id>");

//This is the issue. Nothing happens when I send "!ping" in the server
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === "!ping") {
        channel.send("pong");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [message event listener not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64394000/90527)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
});
```

This will enable you to receive the `MESSAGE_CREATE` event for messages sent in guilds.

A full list of intents can be found [on the Discord developer docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents).

Additionally, if you are using Discord.js v13, [the `message` event has been deprecated](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#naming-conventions) as it has been renamed to `messageCreate`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent. Try this:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.login("<bot token>");

client.once("ready", () => {
console.log("Ready!");

channel.send("hello world"); //This works

const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("<server id>");
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("<channel id>");

//This is the issue. Nothing happens when I send "!ping" in the server
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === "!ping") {
        channel.send("pong");
    }
});
});
```