# My discord bot isn't working after 13.0.0

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying out discord.js version 13.1.0 and I am following discord's guide on how to setup a bot. I have followed all the steps. When I have the bot running, and I send a message or a command into the server, nothing gets printed to the console. Any ideas?

My code:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ready!");
});

client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
  console.log(interaction);
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: A message will not emit the interaction event, have you tried using `messageCreate`

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[message event listener not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64394000/90527)", "[Having trouble sending a message to a channel with Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68795635/90527)", "[Discord bot is not replying to messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68804831/90527)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#interactions):

> An Interaction is the message that your application receives when a user uses an application command or a message component.

By an *application command* is meant a special type of command, that you have to register against the Discord API. To learn more about application commands, read [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#application-commands).

From the discord.js [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) main page, how to register an application (slash) command:

```js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');

const commands = [{
  name: 'ping',
  description: 'Replies with Pong!'
}]; 

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken('token');

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

    await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILD_ID),
      { body: commands },
    );

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

However if you are looking for a way to reply to (or just capture) a normal message sent in a `TextChannel`, you are probably looking for the `messageCreate` event.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Also note that to receive `messageCreate` event, you need `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I changed up my intents and it now responds to messages.