# Can't find a way to make my discord.js bot detect messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
import { Client, Intents } from 'discord.js';
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});
client.on("message", async msg => {
    if (msg.content === "ping") {
        console.log("ping")
        msg.reply("pong")
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

I'm using discord.js v13, the bot logs in correctly and outputs "Ready!" and then when I type a message in the server it's online in it doesn't even `console.log`

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Also duplicate of: "[message event listener not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64394000/90527)", "[Having trouble sending a message to a channel with Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68795635/90527)", "[Discord bot is not replying to messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68804831/90527)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message), the event `message` is deprecated. You can use instead a listener for the event [`messageCreated`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) if you want to listen for any new message.

So you can try something like

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    console.log("ping");
    msg.reply("pong");
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

As [@chickensalt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68982671/10301322) pointed out, you have to declare in your `Intents` the appropriate one  for handling messages, that is `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES`. So, when creating your `Client`:

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intent.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

But remember to use the correct Intent for your needs, because you could have some trouble in handling memory correctly. As the [docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#tracking-state) suggests:

> For larger bots, client state can grow to be quite large. We recommend only storing objects in memory that are needed for a bot's operation. Many bots, for example, just respond to user input through chat commands. These bots may only need to keep guild information (like guild/channel roles and permissions) in memory, since `MESSAGE_CREATE` and `MESSAGE_UPDATE` events have the full member object available.

Comment: I edited my answer so, please, try it out

Answer (score 1):

You need the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent enabled to receive message events. Additionally, as CcmU said, the `message` event is deprecated, and should be replaced with `messageCreate`.

```js
// ...
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
// ...
client.on("messageCreate", async msg => { /* ... */ })
// ...
```