# JS Discord Bot gets online but doesn't respond to messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I recently set up a JavaScript discord bot with node.js and visual studio. While the bot shows up as online, it doesn't respond to the messages that I send to it. I made sure to give the bot proper permissions and I read my code over and over but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I don't normally write JavaScript and any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: post your code as text, not images

Comment: Also duplicate of "[Having trouble sending a message to a channel with Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68795635/90527)", "[Discord bot is not replying to messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68804831/90527)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have not requested the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] })
```